# Postfix: Force Relay to remote server with same domain name

Tags: postfix-mta

My mail server only has one email account and will be using other server on the internet as relay host. The problem is that i need the local server with the same domain name as the remote(relay server). When i send an email to other email account with the same domain name the postfix validate it an returned error 550 because the recipient account doesn't exist on local server but it does in the remote (relay server).

It is possible to force to relay and send the email to the relay serve even thought the recipient account doesn't exist locally?

Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

add   in main.cf

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and in /etc/postfix/header_checks ==>

```
/^[tT]o:.*@domain.com.*/ FILTER smtp:remote.smtp.arelay.com 
/^[tT]o:.*localAcout@domain.com.*/ FILTER smtp:local.smpt.arelay.com
```

then run the following commands:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/header_checks
postfix reload
```

PS: You must adapt this to your environement